# iOS7 No barTintColor on launch

Tags: ios7, launch, navigationbar, tintcolor

When I open my app, during the new animation of io7, the navigation bar is transparent and black without the color that I chose for barTintColor until the app loads. Why is this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because the `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent` was `YES`. Setting it to `NO` fixed the problem. It also changes the color of my barTintColor and I had to adjust accordingly just FYI

Answer (score 0):

```
UIColor *NavBarTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.223 green:0.223 blue:0.223 alpha:1.000];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

At ios7, I use below code to set the color and it worked for me:

```
myNav.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```